# Performance impact of not closing propel connection

Tags: performance, symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel, database-performance

I'm using symfony 1.4/propel 1.4 for a project, which was made by other developer earlier. On that project, propel connection is taken by using following code

```
$con = Propel::getConnection(UsersPeer::DATABASE_NAME, Propel::CONNECTION_WRITE);
```

However it never closes the connection using

```
Propel::close();
```

I just searched that there are 1500+ such incidents of opening connection & I guess none of them is closing connection.

I know its always good practice to close connection but in present case, it seems I wont be able to fix them all as fixing all the incidents is definitely going to take lot of time, may be a whole day. So now I'm confused if I should fix that or not. If I let it be like that, will it have any performance impact?

**EDIT: Just for reference**

Part 2 of this question [Use of closing database connection in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366539/use-of-closing-database-connection-in-php/12366613)

Comment: Do they connect to Propel each time ?! Theorically it's done by Symfony and you don't have to manage the opening/closing. By the way, I guess PHP close the connection at the end of each script if you don't tell it to explicit do it. This usually perform on the `__destruct` object. See [this question/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809248/mysql-database-connection-not-closed-what-will-happen).

Comment: Not always but mostly in case of transaction operation. However I found few places where it is happening for simple query too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anything, explicitly closing connections may *harm* performance.  PDO often caches connections from one request to the next, on the reasonable assumption that the next request will use the same credentials.

Edit: reading the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php), it looks to me like PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT connections are cached regardless of any attempt to close them, so you might as well not bother.

Comment: By first para, does it mean "one should not close the connection" explicitly? If yes, what is the recommended use of Propel::close()

Comment: IMHO, I don't think you ever really need to call close().  And I wouldn't worry about calling getConnection() over and over again - Propel has it's own connection caching, so you're just getting the same connection back each time.